# Long boot and resume times on 2008 MacBook

Tags: release-loki, boot, macbook

I just installed elementary OS (Loki) on a 13" early **2008 MacBook (dual boot w/ rEFInd)**, and so far everything works fine except **booting up and resuming from sleep taking extraordinarily long** (think minutes).

In fact, the dmesg log hints on an issue with a *drm_kms_helper* and points to a path which seems like it’s related to the GPU (see [full dmesg output](https://p3k.keybase.pub/elementary%20OS/dmesg.txt) for stacktrace and more details):

```
[10626.784081] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:34:pipe B] flip_done timed out
[10626.888082] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[10626.888142] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 7509 at /build/linux-hwe-lyR8gz/linux-hwe-4.10.0/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_irq.c:1237 drm_wait_one_vblank+0x1aa/0x1b0 [drm]
```

These messages repeat about 20 times per boot and seem to cost 10 seconds each if I get the dmesg output straight…

I found a similar error description over at [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=13664911#post13664911) where it is related to the **Intel GM965 chipset** (which is onboard the MacBook, too – see lspci output). There, one commenter suggests to set the **`video=SVIDEO-1:d`** kernel parameter in Grub – but as I am using rEFInd I don’t know how to apply this solution in my case.

Of course, I could be completely on the wrong track; thus, here is all the output I could possibly think of, which might be needed for the knowers out there – any help is very much appreciated:

#### 1. lscpu

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 23
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T8300  @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:              6
CPU MHz:               1800.000
CPU max MHz:           2400,0000
CPU min MHz:           800,0000
BogoMIPS:              4788.13
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm
```

#### 2. lspci -v

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
  Capabilities: <access denied>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
  Memory at d0100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
  Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
  I/O ports at 6110 [size=8]
  [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: i915
  Kernel modules: i915, intelfb

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary)
  Flags: fast devsel
  Memory at d0200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=1M]
  Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
  Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 20
  I/O ports at 60c0 [size=32]
  Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller
  Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
  I/O ports at 60a0 [size=32]
  Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller
  Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 21
  Memory at d0704c00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
  Memory at d0700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
  Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
  Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
  I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
  Memory behind bridge: d0600000-d06fffff
  Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0800000-00000000d09fffff
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: pcieport
  Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
  Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
  I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
  Memory behind bridge: d0500000-d05fffff
  Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0000000-00000000d00fffff
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: pcieport
  Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
  Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
  I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff
  Memory behind bridge: d0400000-d04fffff
  Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0a00000-00000000d0bfffff
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: pcieport
  Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller
  Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
  I/O ports at 6080 [size=32]
  Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller
  Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18
  I/O ports at 6060 [size=32]
  Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller
  Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
  I/O ports at 6040 [size=32]
  Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller
  Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 20
  Memory at d0704800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev f3) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
  Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=32
  Memory behind bridge: d0300000-d03fffff
  Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller
  Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
  Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller
  Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
  I/O ports at 6108 [size=8]
  I/O ports at 6124 [size=4]
  I/O ports at 6100 [size=8]
  I/O ports at 6120 [size=4]
  I/O ports at 60e0 [size=16]
  Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
  Kernel modules: pata_acpi

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
  Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
  I/O ports at 60f8 [size=8]
  I/O ports at 611c [size=4]
  I/O ports at 60f0 [size=8]
  I/O ports at 6118 [size=4]
  I/O ports at 6020 [size=32]
  Memory at d0704000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: ahci
  Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller
  Flags: medium devsel
  Memory at d0705000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256]
  I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
  Kernel modules: i2c_i801

02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 03)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme
  Physical Slot: 4
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
  Memory at d0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
  Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=1M]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: wl
  Kernel modules: ssb, wl

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8058 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
  Subsystem: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Imac 8,1 Wired Ethernet Adapter
  Physical Slot: 5
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
  Memory at d0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
  I/O ports at 5000 [size=256]
  Expansion ROM at d0420000 [disabled] [size=128K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: sky2
  Kernel modules: sky2

04:03.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): LSI Corporation FW322/323 [TrueFire] 1394a Controller (rev 61) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
  Subsystem: LSI Corporation FW322/323 [TrueFire] 1394a Controller
  Flags: bus master, fast Back2Back, medium devsel, latency 248, IRQ 19
  Memory at d0300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
  Kernel modules: firewire_ohci
```

#### 3. systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @9.601s
└─multi-user.target @9.601s
  └─getty.target @9.601s
    └─getty@tty1.service @9.601s
      └─[0;1;31mrc-local.service @9.571s +4ms[0m
        └─network-online.target @9.570s
          └─[0;1;31mNetworkManager-wait-online.service @2.633s +6.936s[0m
            └─[0;1;31mNetworkManager.service @2.377s +229ms[0m
              └─dbus.service @2.321s
                └─basic.target @2.221s
                  └─sockets.target @2.219s
                    └─uuidd.socket @2.216s
                      └─sysinit.target @2.185s
                        └─swap.target @2.168s
                          └─[0;1;31mdev-mapper-cryptswap1.swap @2.150s +16ms[0m
                            └─dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device @2.147s
```

#### 4. systemd plot

[image]

#### 5. dmesg

[Download](https://p3k.keybase.pub/elementary%20OS/dmesg.txt)

#### 6. Xorg.0.log

[Download](https://p3k.keybase.pub/elementary%20OS/Xorg.0.log)

#### 7. refind.conf

[Download](https://p3k.keybase.pub/elementary%20OS/refind.conf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution indeed is adding the line `video=SVIDEO-1:d` to the kernel parameters.

I achieved this now by installing rEFInd from within the Linux installation ([source](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html#ppa)):

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install refind
```

This automatically created a file called `refind_linux.conf` in the `/boot/EFI/refind` directory.

(Alternatively, the [documentation](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/linux.html#quickstart) states I could have created it by running the command `mkrlcnf` which comes with the rEFInd package.)

I opened the file with `sudo pico /boot/EFI/refind/refind_linux.conf` and saw three lines **similar** to this:

```
"Boot with standard options"  "ro root=UUID=084f544a-7559-4d4b-938a-b920f59edc7e splash=silent quiet showopts "
"Boot to single-user mode"    "ro root=UUID=084f544a-7559-4d4b-938a-b920f59edc7e splash=silent quiet showopts single"
"Boot with minimal options"   "ro root=UUID=084f544a-7559-4d4b-938a-b920f59edc7e"
```

Now I simply appended `video=SVIDEO-1:d` to the first line (before the quotes and with a leading space), rebooted and – voilà! – the speed gain is enormous!

```
"Boot with standard options"  "ro root=UUID=084f544a-7559-4d4b-938a-b920f59edc7e splash=silent quiet showopts video=SVIDEO-1:d"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!! Now my laptop boots so fast, unbelievable :-)

At home my laptop is in a docking station with another monitor and I did not notice any problems but now I am somewhere else and I have to use the laptop display and found out that there were a few crashes while booting but your solution works! 
I have changed `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` and added the kernel parameter:

```
linux<->${rel_dirname}/${basename} root=${linux_root_device_thisversion} ro video=SVIDEO-1:d ${args}
```

Now the `grub-mkconfig` puts that parameter at every kernel